# Makefile: target with pattern does not work

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My Makefile looks like this:

```
BIN     = bin
OBJECTS = object1.o \
          object2.o \
          object3.o
HDR     = $(OBJECTS:%.o=%.h) header1.h header2.h
MAIN    = main.c

CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -g -std=c99 -fstack-protector-all
LDFLAGS = -lpthread

$(BIN): $(OBJECTS) $(MAIN)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c $(HDR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

It seems that the `%.o: %.c $(HDR)` rule is not used. When invoking with option `make -r` it says that there's no rule to make target `object.o`. The build of each object file should depend on every header file. What am I missing?

**Edit:** I should mention that when doing `echo $(HDR)` than it looks like the variable contains the right values:
`object1.h object2.h object3.h header1.h header2.h`

Comment: Could you try `make -d object.o`, and look at the last twenty lines or so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the given Makefile should work, I had a typo in one of the header file names.

It's a pitty, but make doesn't warn about that. It seems that when a pattern based rule is missing a prerequisite than it's just ignored. The built-in `.o` creation rule is used instead.

Jonathan Leffler's proposal of `${OBJECTS}: ${HDR}` brought that up, because than there's an error regarding "no rule to make target misspelled.h" - I would have expected that from my rule too.

So I can just agree to fluffy, it's better to use auto-generated dependencies instead.

Comment: That's a feature. You can have more than one implicit rule rule that fits a target, and the first one whose prerequisites exist (or can be built) is the one Make uses.

Answer (score 2):

In the declaration of HDR, try $(OBJECTS:.o=.h) instead. Or, better yet, use `gcc -MM` or the like to [generate your dependencies instead](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html).

Comment: Hm, okay, I have no idea what's going on then.  But still, manual dependency management is kind of a bad idea, and you should look into gcc -MM to generate a .depend file or the like (see the link in my answer).

Comment: I just edited my question to mention that HDR (seems to) contains the correct values.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea what's going on here.  It's still a good idea in general to use automatic dependency generation.  Jonathan Leffler's answer seems more plausible.

Answer (score 2):

A pattern rule can't have auxilliary dependencies like `${HDR}`.

Use:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

${OBJECTS}: ${HDR}
```

Comment: That's not what the GNU make manual says: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro

Comment: Indeed the problem seems to be the $(HDR). When stating the prerequisites explicitly, like "%.o: %.c header1.h header2.h ..." it seems to work.